# Hide view when node's taxonomy value is empty

Tags: 8, views

I have two taxonomy vocabularies: *departments* and *categories*.

I created a block view to display related pages (other pages in the same *department* **and** *category*) using contextual filter. All works well when a node has **both** *department* and *category* selected. But when I leave the *category* empty on a node, the view still shows other pages from the same *department*.

Is there any way to make the view not show up on the nodes with no *category*?

Here is what my contextual filter looks like:

[image: Contextual filter settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of my co-worker, we were able to make it work by adding two contextual filters: one for *category* and one for *department* taxonomy:

[image: Category contextual filter][image: Department contextual filter]

All other check boxes unchecked.